# Eclipse IDE Shows Warnings On Project When None Exist

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

I recently changed the JRE that one of my Java Projects use in Eclipse IDE from `JavaSE-1.8` to `JavaSE-11`. I restarted Eclipse. Now most of my Projects have warnings even though none of the files have warnings.

[image]

There also aren't any warnings in the build path libraries.
I tried:

- refreshing Projects Explorer
- creating compile warning than removing it
- running project
- restarting Eclipse

none have fixed the issue, all warnings remained.

When I create a new Java Project, it also will have a warning on it. Hovering over the warning does not show anything.

Though the Projects do run as normal, why are the warnings there and how can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Problems view (*Window* > *Show View* > *Problems*). This will list the actual problem. It's probably something about the test folder having a wonky configuration aspect to it. I give it 95%+ odds there's an actual problem here. If truly there is none, or it doesn't seem like it applies, then:
2. clean the project: (*Project* > *Clean* > tick *Clean all Problems* > Press *Clean*).
3. Close the project (right click on the project, then *Close Project*), and double click on it to open it again.

Comment: I see 2 warning descriptions that stand out "Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.8. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment." and "The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 14 is used"

Comment: The first one is because JDK 11 doesn't come with a JRE, and the second one I am not sure. I never used a JRE for Java 14, I don't think I even have the JRE.

Comment: _The first one is because JDK 11 doesn't come with a JRE_ __No__, that is not the reason. JREs are effectively dead, eclipse kind of unfortunately uses it here. The point of that message is: You've set the project to j8, but have no j8 installed on your system (or at least, not told eclipse about it: Window > Preferences. Add the JDK. Alternatively, change project to a j14 project.